Why doing query.from multiple times returns wrong count?
I recently stumbled upon this weird behaviour which I can't quite explain.
If I do
public Long getAllUsersCount() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

    Root<Userr> root = query.from(Userr.class);         // exp = 3; act = 3             exp = 2; act = 2
    //Root<Userr> root2 = query.from(Userr.class);      // exp = 3; act = 9 = 3^2       exp = 2; act = 6
    //Root<Userr> root3 = query.from(Userr.class);      // exp = 3; act = 27 = 3^3      exp = 2; act = 18

    query.select(cb.count(root));

    //query.where(cb.equal(root.get("name"), "josh"));

    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}

I correctly get 3 (EXPected = ACTual).
When I uncomment root2 I get 9 which is 3 squared.
Furthermore, when I also uncomment root3 I get 27 which is 3 cubed.
Now let's comment root1 and root2 again but uncomment the where.
With only one root I correctly get 2 (EXPected = ACTual).
When I uncomment root2 I get 6.
And when I also uncomment root3 I get 18.
This is the data I'm working with
INSERT INTO userr (id, name, email) VALUES
  (1, 'josh', 'josh@a.com'),
  (2, 'josh', 'josh@b.com'),
  (3, 'coby', 'coby@a.com');

It looks like the count increases as I increase the number of query.from.
I know I should use only one root, but I just want to understand why this happens. Do you have any idea?
Also it only happens on the count. A normal select always returns the correct items, no matter how many times I do query.from.

I wonder if Long.class is your custom class??? and if it is then maybe some ambiguity for the runtime?  You don't require the java.lang to the compiler or runtime. Is it your Long class or the jre/sdk?

Calling Root-userr appears to be placing a root into the previous as a tree in the (original/previous) "collection".

It's the sdk Long class.

For every Query root, you add a 'FROM' in the final query, so you get the cartesian product, since you have no join cirteria.
If you select objects, jpa does some grouping on its own on the object.
You should add sql logging to see the generated statements ...

Both @turo comment and @rob-spoor answer helped me understand what's happening. But I wanted to elaborate a bit more to also describe what happens when we add a where clause.
Doing query.from doesn't overwrite the previouse query.from but it adds a new table to the from using the cross join. For example, starting from 1 root to n roots, this is the equivalent sql query:

1 root = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userr;
2 roots = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userr, userr;
n roots = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userr, ..., userr;

In my example I had a table with 3 rows.

1 root = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userr; = 3
2 roots = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userr, userr; = number of rows of the table resulting from the cross join between userr and userr = 3x3 = 9
3 roots = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userr, userr, userr; = 3x3x3 = 27

Nice! But what happens when i add the where clause? In this case the where applies only to the first table. Let's see it in practice:

1 root = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userr WHERE name = 'josh'; = 2
2 roots = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userr, userr WHERE name = 'josh'; = take only users which name is 'josh' from the first userr table (there's two joshes), then do the cross join with the second userr table which has all three users = 2x3 = 6
3 roots = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userr, userr, userr WHERE name = 'josh'; = 2x3x3 = 18

But what happens when we do just a simple select and not the count?
Apparently JPA implicitly applies a DISTINCT on the primary key. That's why, no matter how many roots we have, the result is always the same as if we only had one root.

You're getting cross joins if you include more than one from.
With only root the executed query is SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Userr root.
If you include root2 the executed query is SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Userr root, Userr root2 which means every record of root is joined with every record of root2.
If you include root3 as well the executed query is SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Userr root, Userr root2, Userr root3 which means that each result from the combined combination of just root and root2 is again joined with every record of root3.
